# Is having extra data in database tables considered as a bad practice?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-administration

Consider the following scenario:

```
chapter(chapter_id*,book_id, chapter_no) 

book(book_id*)

user(user_id*)

position(user_id*,book_id,chapter_id*)
```

- = (component of) PRIMARY KEY

When I want to know in which chapter of a book the user currently is, I simply query the **Position** table with certain **User** and **Book**. But the problem is that the foreign key to **Book** is garbage here because the **Chapter** specifies the **Book** already!

What should I do now?

Comment: If you don't need a column - drop it. Or is there any reason to keep it?

Comment: Or... the reverse - because you don't really need a chapter table at all, do you? Or is this abstracted from a more complicated scenario?

Comment: I think you could eliminate the chapter table by putting chapter_no into the position table. That's just my guess. If chapter_id determines book_id then the presence of both attributes in the position table seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, I have a more complicated scenario, if I delete the book_id column, queries become more complicated and if I keep it, well, it's garbage and it adds the possibility of storing a chapter_id which isn't in the corresponding book at all!

Comment: Well, without knowing more about the real situation, it's really hard to advise.

Answer (score 1):

It's always depending of queries you will do against database. You will have to decide if duplicate a value worth to avoid a JOIN.

With what you give I would drop the chapter table and simply use

`position(user_id*,book_id,chapter_no)`

Can it be enough for your application ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my example was just an abstraction and I have a more complicated scenario, so I can't delete the chapter table! Also if I delete the book_id column, queries become more complicated and if I keep it, well, it's garbage and it adds the possibility of storing a chapter_id which isn't in the corresponding book at all!

Comment: So I would go LEAN. Drop the column for now, use  join and if later you need optimisation you will think about adding the book_id

Answer (score 1):

I think your design is valid, and `position.book_id` isn't "garbage" at all. You wrote:

> When I want to know in which chapter of a book the user currently is [..]

So it sounds like a user can have only one "position" per book, and your unique/primary key should be `user_id,book_id` instead of `user_id,chapter_id`.

In order to prevent a foreign key mismatch (`book_id` and `chapter_id` do not match) you can define a compound foregn key `(book_id, chapter_id) referencing chapter(book_id, chapter_id)`.